# Cannot figure out regex pattern for requirements (javascript split pattern)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to figure out a regex pattern for the following string & requirements.

```
this. i s.a.string .but. so is . this
```

Expected result:

```
1 - "this. i s"
2 - "a"
3 - "string .but. so is . this"
```

The separation must be done on `.`, however, not if it has a white-space **before or after**, then it should be part of the preceding result.

I've been trying variations on the following (with results)

```
/[(^?=\.]+|[^?<=\.]+/g
1 - "this"
2 - "."
3 - " i s"
4 - "."
5 - "a"
6 - "."
7 - "string"

/[^?<=\.]+/g OR /[^\.]+/g
1 - "this"
2 - " i s"
3 - "a"
4 - "string"
```

Edit: Updated string & expected results. Based on uncertainty I saw in comments/answers that have been deleted.

Comment: The problem is js doesn't have a  *look behind* feature :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this regex:

```
[^. ]+(( \.|\. | )[^. ]*)*
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/mCz3wx/1) how it works.

Comment: Using [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with the global flag (`/.../g`) this works in a one-liner as opposed to [Rajesh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43256965/1155833). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Look for pattern *`not space` followed by `.` followed by `not space`* and replace the first `not space` to `not space|`
- Now split using `|.` to get your list of groups

```js
function getGroups(str){
  var replaceRegex = /(\S)(?=\.\S)/g;
  var g = str.replace(replaceRegex, "$1|").split("|.");
  console.log(g)
  return g;
}

getGroups("this. i s.a.string");
getGroups("this . i s.a.string");
getGroups("this . i 1.a.string");
getGroups("127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: try it with `"this . i s.a.string"`

Comment: \w - is not equivalent to "not space", the latter is "\S"

Comment: @Rajesh https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace_non.asp

Answer (score 0):

With `lookahead` and `lookbehind`, the split regex would be:

```
(?<! )\.(?! )
```

But JavaScript does not support look behind, one trick to do it is:

```
var s = "this. i s.a.string .but. so is . this";
s.replace(/([^ ])\.(?! )/g, "$1__special__").split("__special__")
```

1. Replace delimiters with `lookahead` and a behind group capture to a special delimiter
2. Split by the newly special delimiter